# How to use R contrast package from glm within a function

Tags: r, function, package, glm, contrast

I have a large dataset for which I am trying to produce a summary table of glm output and I have some interaction terms for which I am using the R contrast package. I am trying to write a function which will provide output based on a list of variables.

I suspect the problem has to do with the formatting of the characters in the namelist as it is input into the contrast function.

I had a similar problem getting the variables from the list to go into the glm function so I ended up using substitute(). However, this strategy did not work within the contrast function and gave the error:

```
reg.con <- contrast(reg, list(substitute(i, list(i = as.name(name))) = 1, intvar = 1), list(substitute(i, list(i = as.name(name))) = 0, intvar = 1))
```

Error: unexpected '=' in "reg.con <- contrast(reg, list(substitute(i, list(i = as.name(name))) ="

I also tried eval(substitute()), paste(name), as.character(name) all which gave the same error.

Of course, just using the variable directly from the list within the function also does not work:

```
reg.con <- contrast(reg, list(name = 1, intvar = 1), list(name = 0, intvar = 1))
```

Error in generateData(fit = list(coefficients = c(`(Intercept)` = -2.2842358778574,  : 
  factor(s) not in design: name

All the vars in namelist, as well as outcome and intvar, are 0/1 coded and have both levels represented in the data.

```
namelist = list('var1', 'var2', 'var3', 'var4') 

results=lapply(namelist, function(name) {

reg = glm(substitute(outcome ~ i*intvar, list(i = as.name(name))), data=mydat, family=binomial)

reg.con <- contrast(reg, list(name = 1, intvar = 1), list(name = 0, intvar = 1))

mat=matrix(nrow=1, ncol=4)
mat[1,1]=as.numeric(exp(reg.con$Contrast))
mat[1,2]=as.numeric(exp(reg.con$Lower))
mat[1,3]=as.numeric(exp(reg.con$Upper))
mat[1,4]=as.numeric(reg.con$Pvalue)
})
```

I expect to get a list of output with the contrast, confidence interval limits, and p-value for each variable in the namelist, but instead I get a variety of different errors as mentioned above.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance!